# How do I join these vertices?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, vertices, faces

While testing the armature of my character, I've noticed that I've messed up the model and now when I move some of her bones around some parts of her body disconnect from each other...

[image]
[image]

I've already tried using ctrl-J to fix it, but it has done what it could and it's still messed up, help?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

P.S.: I've heard of it but now I forgot what command fixes faces that are occupying the same place like in this situation...

[image]
[image]

Any help on that too?

Comment: "Remove Dubles"

Comment: While Remove Doubles should help you (note - weight paint might be required to be edited), rigging triangulated character can create more problems further on, specifically with shading.

Answer (score -4):

select d 2 vertices u want to join den hit d V botton on d keyboard dat sud do it but u cant do multuple vertices at d same time it has to be one b4 another

Comment: Surely it's the M for merge key, V will rip the vertex (the complete opposite).  Also please use full words.